# How to use function declared in js file that built by webpack in html?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

So, what I'm trying to do is, generate a html file called `index.html` based on `template.html`, that have styling based on `style.css` and a function `handleClick` that declared in `index.js`. The code below works for the styling, but the `handleClick` is not working. Is this possbile?

This is my `webpack.config.js`

```
const path = require('path')
const HTMLWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        'page': './src/index.js'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist'),
        filename: "[name].js"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    'babel-loader'  
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    "style-loader",
                    "css-loader"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
            filename: 'index.html',
            template: './src/template.html'
        })
    ]
}
```

this is my `index.js`

```
require('./style.css');
function handleClick(){
    alert("called from index")
}
```

this is my `template.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>My Page's Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>This background should be blue</div>
    <button onclick="handleClick()"> click me </button>
  </body>
</html>
```

and this is my `style.css`

```
div {
 background-color:blue;
}
```

Comment: is it possible to `require` a css file and declare a function in the same script file that will be used in the generated html file?  I tried to load the js file with `script-loader`, but then the style won't load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better way is to add `addEventListener` to that element using your js file. You can do it like this:

```
<button id="buttonWithFunction"> click me </button>

<script>
// pure js
document.getElementById('buttonWithFunction').addEventListener('click', handleClick);

//with jquery loaded
$('#buttonWithFunction').on('click',function() {
     handleClick();
})
```

You may need to wrap the following in a document.onload for that to work.

Comment: So what I'm trying to do is not possible? Because if I put this code

`function handleClick(){ alert("called from index") }`

in the generated js file `page.js`, the button will work as expected

Comment: It's not necessarily impossible, as nothing in code is (with limitations). However, it's much better practice keeping everything separate. You keep html, css and js separate so that maintenance of the code is much easier. 

I believe what you might be trying to do is to [expose the webpack as a library](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-library). This allows you to use it as any other library. Also I wouldn't necesarilly advise changing the generated file, as any changes there would be overwritten with every webpack

Comment: I tried it and your answer is working without having to wrap the code in a `document.onload`. What I'm actually want to do is write javascript function (without having to add my element an event listener), and use it in the generated html in a simple way. (I mean, it's kinda troublesome if I have to add an event listener to all the button that I'll have eventually), and yeah we can move the css to dedicated script, is this possible? or I have to add the listener manually?

Comment: I'm still not certain what you're using this for. Or what the application of your specific integration is for this.

Some of this is also going out of scope of the original question, and some is slightly confusing to me. What does 'move the css to dedicated script'?

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm confusing you, lets just forget my previous comment as this question already answered

Answer (score 0):

Suggest to check namespace of index.js - as i expect, webpack will wrap it in a namespace.
Try to define function on a window namespace.

```
window.handleClick = () => console.log('Clicked');
```